# Sharing data between siblings w/tabs

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using chakra-ui to build a web app, in which I have three tabs, each with their own state. The state of each tab should be shared between all the other tabs. But if I lift up all the states to the parent and pass them as props to each tab, it gets laggy because every time I change something in a tab, it rerenders everything.

Are there other ways to share data between them or, if only lift state up works, prevent rerender of inactive tabs?

```
<Tabs>
<TabList>
    <Tab>Cálculos</Tab>
    <Tab>Gráficos</Tab>
    <Tab>Resultados</Tab>
</TabList>
<Stack direction='row'>
    <TabPanels >
        <TabPanel m={0} p={0} w='full' h='full'>
            <Calculations testStarted={testStarted} />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel m={0} p={0} w='full' h='full'>
            <Graphics testStarted={testStarted} />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel m={0} p={0} w='full' h='full'>
            <Results testStarted={testStarted} />
        </TabPanel>
    </TabPanels>
</Stack>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useContext

React Beta docs has a good visual tutorial on this:

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context